# How can I set my Git user.name differently in different projects?

Tags: git, github

I am working on two projects. And I have set the Git configuration

```
git config --global user.name "xxx"
```

When I switch project I want to change the name for the project, setting up same configuration back again.

How can I set different names for the different projects in Git?

Comment: Ohk sorry . But I was searching with defferent words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just omit the `--global` option to configure each repo separately.  And see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/27/10397393.aspx

Answer (score 2):

in each git project, after you `git init` just do

```
git config user.name "xxx"
```